# Grails View Renders Extra Comma For DTO Object List

Tags: grails

I am working on upgrading a Grails 4.0.0 app to 4.0.4. Application is mostly working working.
I am having trouble with one GSON view that returns a collection of DTO's (not a domain object).

Versions: Grails 4.0.4, GORM 7.0.6.RELEASE, Win10, openjdk 1.8.0_262

It returns an array of expected objects but, in 4.0.4, with an extra comma before the fields after the opening curly bracket i.e.:

```
[{,*MY EXPECTED OBJECT 1 DATA*} , {,*MY EXPECTED OBJECT 2 DATA*}]
```

which upsets the client. The view looks like:

```
    import com.myapp.dto.MyDTO
    
    model {
        List<MyDTO> MyDTOList
    }
    
    json g.render(template: "itemView", collection: MyDTOList)
```

The MyDTOList view causes the problem even with just one field:

```
    json g.render(MyDTO) {
    afield MyDTO.afield
    }
```

If I remove the afield from the view (i.e. a blank view) then no extra comma is inserted. Please let me know if I can provide more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't described the desired structure of the response but here is a reasonable guess...

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/daftspanieljson.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/daftspanieljson/blob/dc54db2dc55db36df16338c88c106e67b1c6ecc4/grails-app/controllers/daftspanieljson/MyDTOController.groovy

```
package daftspanieljson

import com.myapp.dto.MyDTO

class MyDTOController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    def index() {
        def data = [new MyDTO(afield: 'MY EXPECTED OBJECT 1 DATA'),
                    new MyDTO(afield: 'MY EXPECTED OBJECT 2 DATA')]

        respond data
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/daftspanieljson/blob/dc54db2dc55db36df16338c88c106e67b1c6ecc4/grails-app/views/myDTO/index.gson

```
import com.myapp.dto.MyDTO

model {
    List<MyDTO> myDTOList
}

json tmpl.itemView(myDTOList)
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/daftspanieljson/blob/dc54db2dc55db36df16338c88c106e67b1c6ecc4/grails-app/views/myDTO/_itemView.gson

```
import com.myapp.dto.MyDTO

model {
    MyDTO myDTO
}

json {
    afield myDTO.afield
}
```

When I run that app and send a request to that action, I get the following response:

```
[
    {
        "afield": "MY EXPECTED OBJECT 1 DATA"
    },
    {
        "afield": "MY EXPECTED OBJECT 2 DATA"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks very much Jeff - this helped massively in solving the issue. I followed through this pattern and removed my uses of  g.render and the views render as expected and the client application is happy.